# MVC4 best practice for DropDownListFor enum from database or code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to MVC and was wondering the best way to populate dropdown's in my editor templates?

I am building an application which has a LOT of dropdowns and the data for those dropdowns is very static.  Currently I have them all in a table in the db, and then load them into session.

Here is an example:

My view:

```
   @{
        var widgettypes = Business.MySession.Current.WidgetTypes.ToSelectList(d => d.TypeName,
                                   d => d.WidgetTypeID.ToString(),
                                   " - Select - ");
    }
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WidgetTypeID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WidgetTypeID, @widgettypes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WidgetTypeID)
    </div>
```

Dropdown Helper:

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
            Func<T, string> text,
            Func<T, string> value,
            string defaultOption)
    {
        var items = enumerable.Select(f => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = text(f),
            Value = value(f)
        }).ToList();
        items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = defaultOption,
            Value = "-1"
        });
        return items;
    }
```

I've seen a LOT of examples here on SO that show creating the select list in the view statically.

Is it best practice to create them in the view from static enum's in .net code or is it best to do it the way I am doing it now?  Or does it just not matter?

I just want to know what I should be doing, and not what just works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally think that database-driven is the way to go. Mainly from experience, say you wanted to add a value into your lookup and you'd already deployed your application, you'd have to re-deploy the code after adding the new value to the Enum. With them being database driven you simply can run an insert query against the database and no re-deploy is required.

I wouldn't call your database in your view like that though, I wouldn't say that was best practice, as that's not the view's responsibility, it just needs to display data, not query for additional data.

First off, put your items you want in your dropdown list in your model, like so:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public int WidgetTypeId { get; set; }
    public SelectList WidgetTypes { get; set; }
    //...rest of your model
}
```

Then, in your GET method in your controller (before returning your view, populate that list with the code you have in the view:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    YourModel model = new YourModel();

    model.WidgetTypes = Business.MySession.Current.WidgetTypes
        .ToSelectList(d => d.TypeName, d => d.WidgetTypeID.ToString(), " - Select - ");

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view just do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WidgetTypeID, Model.WidgetTypes)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your solution.  I guess my only real issue is that the application I am developing has about 90+ different forms which means I have to write custom Get() methods for each, and it'll be quite a bit of work...blah.  I know it's wrong to load from the view (or editortemplate) but it was a better solution for me to have less code as some forms will share templates.

Comment: Also, I have another issue - what if I'm binding my EditorTemplate directly to a Entity Framework POCO model - I now have ot create view models for EACH one and then instance them all over my controllers...how is this a better solution?  The ONLY advantage I see is full separation of concerns.

Comment: Another issue I am seeing - I now have to object copy back in forth between my EF poco's and the model instances...yuck!

Comment: Because strictly speaking you shouldn't really expose your POCO as a model, there is overhead because you have to create view models, but if you're adhering to best practices, that IS necessary overhead. In an ideal world, your web project wouldn't even have any knowledge of the EF classes, your models would be in a Core layer, which would talk to a Data layer (EF layer) and the Web layer, your controller calls a method on Core to populate and return a view model, that method in Core in turn populates the view model based on retrieving data objects (if necessary).

Comment: Do you happen to have an example project of this approach?  I'm pretty sure I understand you, I just would like to see a working example.  I guess I am struggling with this because in aspx world, all of this extra 'work' wasn't needed, however the site didn't have the best SOC.  I can see why MVC is good at this, but when it comes to making business apps (ie 90+ unique forms + custom validation) this is actually causing me MORE 'work' than an aspx site

Comment: ...this isn't good when billing customers or building projects that require swift deployment.  I guess my biggest question here is, why should I adopt MVC over ASPX to build very complex business applications?  I'm not really seeing the value EXCEPT in the views where it's completely separated (which I do like).  Aside from that I'm lengthening my deployment window and it's costing me more to build the site because I have to pay a developer way more time to 'do it right'.  Do you feel MVC is suited for large complex business applications or is better suited for simpler sites?

Comment: Not an open source solution unfortunately not, only proprietary work for places I've worked for. Although, you're using a real-world example now: Stackoverflow is built in ASP.NET MVC http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/ Rest assured, although taking the MVC approach can be MORE work (which is usually because a lot of the stuff is done for you already in Web Forms), the end product will be a much more robust, performant solution.

Comment: And in terms of billing customers for swift deployment projects, that's exactly what the company does that I work for and we use MVC always. As with anything, the more you use it, the faster you'll be able to build projects. Honestly, I didn't see what the fuss was about when I moved to MVC 2 years ago, but quite frankly nowadays I've never looked back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22780/discussion-between-steve-stokes-and-mattytommo)

Comment: @SteveStokes. I had the same concerns about swift development when switching from webforms (1.5 years ago). Once you get to grips with MVC you'll start to find it quicker, easier, and tidier than webforms. Also, don't cut corners. You'll regret it later. The correct solution isn't always the one that takes the longest. Quite often, it's  the other way around. And when you start to factor in maintenance and extensibility, there's only one way to do it - the right way.

Comment: flem, thanks. @mattytommo & flem - Should I be using automapper(or what?) to map from objects in my view models back to my EF models or what is the proper way to do this?  Or should I be adding populated EF models to my view models however I want?  A lot of the forms I have to create will be using the fields from the database quite a bit.

Comment: If you have both the EF model and the view model implement the same interface, you could have a constructor for each that takes in the interface and maps the fields to the corresponding class. If you need anything from me, feel free to email me mattytommo@gmail.com